# is there a way to create a Python internal table with 3 or more fields?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
#User table, this is where the user orders a material
tab_user = {
 'USER1': 'MAT1',
 'USER2': 'MAT1',
 'USER3': 'MAT3',
 'USER4': 'MAT4' }

#Type table, this determine the material type
tab_type = {
 'MAT1': 'FERT',
 'MAT2': 'ROH',
 'MAT3': 'FERT',
 'MAT4': 'ZZZ1' 
}

#this is my code to get what did the user order, this output 'FERT'

print( tab_type.get( tab_user.get( 'USER1' ) ) )
```

I'm stuck on how to count the orders base on its type (eg, for FERT we have 3, and for ZZZ1:1, and ROH:0)
i'm thinking to have a 3 field table but i'm not sure how

Comment: you can convert your dictionary to dataframe. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html

Comment: @chuam2 How did you get ROH:2?

Comment: Use `print(Counter(tab_type.values()))` where Couner is from [collections module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: @Gabip sorry about the confusion should be ROH:0

Comment: @DarrylG thank you, i used this but still don't know how to connect the count from two tables x = collections.Counter(tab_type.values( ))

Comment: @chuam2--Are you trying to get the count of orders by type for different users?  Seems this is the only reason why both tables would be involved.

Comment: @chuam2--also why are 'USER1' and 'USER2' both called "MAT1'?

Comment: @DarrylG, no that means user1 and user2 buys material1, but i guess dict is not a good way to represent this, so i'm starting to study data handling like PANDA as suggested here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one:

```
# STEP 1 - convert ordered materials to types 
ordered_types = [tab_type.get(m) for m in tab_user.values()]

# STEP 2 - iterate over all types, in order to includes those with zero orders, and count how many times each was ordered based on the first list
output = {t: ordered_types.count(t) for t in tab_type.values()}

print(output) # {'FERT': 3, 'ROH': 0, 'ZZZ1': 1}
```

Comment: thank you @Gabip this works, I didn't think to use a list to be referenced in creating a dictionary